# Making http get requests with headers and query parameters in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm trying to make an get request to the [Newscatcher API](https://docs.newscatcherapi.com/api-docs/authentication) with the code given below

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  var queryParameters = {
    'q':'Tesla',
  };
  
  var headers = {
  'x-api-key': 'apikeyhidden'
};
  
  var url = Uri.https('api.newscatcherapi.com', '/v2/search', queryParameters);
  var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
  
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    print('$jsonResponse');
  } else {
    print('Reponse error with code ${response.statusCode}');
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error code

```
Response error with code 401
```

Please help to solve this issue.

I'm using [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/).

Comment: tried to print `${response.body}`? does it have any additional info?

Comment: make sure API key is true

Comment: @MojtabaGhiasi API key is valid and got it from the newscatcher dashboard by creating an account.

Comment: @pskink I used this else statement to just notify me of the type of error I'm receiving.

Comment: what does `${response.body}` contain? tried to `print` it?

Comment: @pskink I can't post the response here

Comment: @pskink here
{
    "status": "error",
    "error_code": "InvalidAPIKey",
    "message": "Invalid api key: false_api_key"
}

Comment: your API key is invalid, double-check your API key

Comment: @MojtabaGhiasi so is the code correct?

Comment: yes, the error is about API key

Comment: so you have the answer: your API key is invalid

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is due to the user providing wrong API KEY.

Comment: @OMiShah I'm getting the message "You can accept your own answer in two days" when I try to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API key was the issue. Issue Closed. I used an expired API key. I tried again with a new API and and it worked.